# findAll with conditions in symfony2

Tags: symfony, repository, entitymanager, findall

is there a way to use the `findAll()` function with conditions?

I want to do something like

```
->findAll('active'=1);
```

I know that i can write custom repository classes but just for a simple "where-condition" I thought there is an easier way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `findBy`:

```
$objects = $yourRepo -> findBy(array('key' => $value ));
```